# ¿Cómo imprimo el mayor y menor de una matriz en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo una matriz 3x3 a la cual se imprimen los valores de cada matriz, despues se suman las dos matrices y despues tengo que imprimir el numero mayor y el numero menor del resultado de la suma.

¿Como hago para que me imprima el numero mayor y el numero menor del resultado de la suma?

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int matriz1[][] = {{3, 2, 4}, {7, 9, 8}, {5, 6, 1}};
    int matriz2[][] = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}};

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Matriz[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + matriz1[i][j]);
        }

    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(":: MOSTRANDO LA MATRIZ # 1 ::");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz1[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(":: MOSTRANDO LA MATRIZ # 2 ::");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz2[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(":: MOSTRANDO LA MATRIZ RESULTADO ::");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print((matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(":: MOSTRANDO EL MENOR Y MAYOR DE LA MATRIZ RESULTADO ::");
    System.out.println();


}
```

Comment: Pues vas llevando cada valor mientras la recorres para mostrarla, con eso la recorres una sola vez y pintas los dos valores después.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te lo dejo con Javascript para que puedas ver como funciona debajo te lo pongo con java

**Javascript**

```js
var matriz1 = [[3, 2, 4], [7, 9, 8], [5, 6, 1]];
var matriz2 = [[1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]];
var impresora=''

console.log(":: MOSTRANDO LA MATRIZ RESULTADO ::");

var maxNumber=0
var posMaxNumber=''
var minNumebr=999;
var posMinNumber=''
for (var i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {
        impresora=impresora+(matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j] + " ");
        if(matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]>maxNumber){
          maxNumber=matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
          posMaxNumber=' -> la psosicion en la matriz seria -> ['+[i]+']['+[j]+']'
        }
        if(matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]<minNumebr){
          minNumebr=matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
          posMinNumber=' -> la psosicion en la matriz seria -> ['+[i]+']['+[j]+']'
        }
    }
    console.log(impresora);
    impresora='';
}
console.log('Numero Maximo ='+maxNumber+posMaxNumber)
console.log('Numero Minimo ='+minNumebr+posMinNumber)
```

Para tu caso en java tendrias esto lo que hace es crear dos variables para almacenar cual es el numero mínimo y el numero máximo y después de los bucles imprimirlo

**Java**

```
    int matriz1[][] = {{3, 2, 4}, {7, 9, 8}, {5, 6, 1}};
    int matriz2[][] = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}};
    int maxNumber=-999;//un numero negativo grande
    int minNumber=999;//un numero positivo grande
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {

            if(matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]>maxNumber){
              maxNumber=matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];

            }
            if((matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j])<minNumber){
              minNumber=matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
            }
        }
   }
System.out.println("numero Maximo ->"+maxNumber+" numero minimo ->"+minNumber);
```

Si tienes alguna duda sobre el código pregúntamelo

Comment: Cuando imprime me aparece los numeros menores mal: " 9  10 9 Numero Mayor -> 10 Numero Menor -> 3"

Comment: Al hacerlo sobre el texto plano puse la impresión dentro del bucle, ya sale bien.
Los números que salían delante eran los del la linea del la matriz ya lo tienes cambiado

Answer (score 0):

Puede agregar variables globales y comparar esos valores mientras recorres la matriz:

```
int mayor = 0;
int menor = matriz2[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < matriz2.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz2[0].length; j++) {
        if matriz2[i][j] > mayor {
            mayor = matriz2[i][j];
        }

        if matriz2[i][j] <= menor {
            menor = matriz2[i][j];
        }

        System.out.print(matriz2[i][j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Luego imprimes las variables `mayor` y `menor`.

```
System.out.println(mayor);
System.out.println(menor);
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso te recomiendo crear dos variables antes de hacer la suma fuera del `for`, una que contenga el numero mayor y otra el numero menor.

```
int menor = 0;
int mayor = 0;
```

Ahora dentro de los `for` creas una nueva variable la cual contendrá la suma de las dos matrices

```
int suma = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
```

Comparas si ambas matrices se encuentran en la primera posición, de ser verdadero el numero mayor sera la suma y el menor también sera la misma suma

```
if(i == 0 && j == 0){
  mayor = suma;
  menor = suma;
}
```

Si no se encuentran en la primera posición las matrices comparas si el valor de la suma es mayor al valor que tiene asignado la variable mayor, de ser verdadero le asignas el valor de la suma;

```
if(suma > mayor){
  mayor = suma;
}
```

Lo mismo haces para el menor, pero en este caso comparas si la suma es menor al menor

```
 if(suma < menor){
   menor = suma;
 }
```

Por ultimo fuera del for imprimes el numero mayor y el numero menor

```
System.out.println("Numero mayor: " + mayor + " Numero menor: " + menor);
```

Quedando todo el código de la siguiente manera

```
int menor = 0;
int mayor = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[0].length; j++) {
        int suma = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
        if(i == 0 && j == 0){
          mayor = suma;
          menor = suma;
        }else{
           if(suma > mayor){
              mayor = suma;
           }
           if(suma < menor){
              menor = suma;
           }
        }
        System.out.print((matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j]) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("Numero mayor: " + mayor + " Numero menor: " + menor);
```